# How to count rows in a connected table as a column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables:

table1

```
Client     Client#
A          001
B          002
C          003
D          004
```

table2

```
Client#   Machine
001       A
001       B
002       A
002       B
002       C
003       A
004       A
```

tables are connected on Client#.  I want to be able to create a column in table 1 that counts the number of machines for that Client# in table 2. So it would look like this:

table1

```
Client   Client#    Machines
A        001        2
B        002        3
C        003        1
D        004        1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding a Calculated column in table 1 like this:

```
Machines = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('table 2')
)
```

This works since calculate takes the current row context and uses it as a filter context.